# Performance comparison between type casting procedures

Tags: python, casting

I am reading lines from a file and want to convert them to a integer list.The file has one million lines.So,I was just wondering which procedure will make it faster.say,
`lst=['10','12','31','41','15']` is the current line which has been read from the file.
I can do the casting using map function,like-
`lst1=map(int,lst)`
or using the for function,like-
`lst2=[int(x) for x in lst]`
Which one would be the most efficient  and the fastest way to do it?

Comment: unless the each list is quite long map won't be much faster, how are you reading the file content into the each list? Also timing the each implementation would answer your question so you can really answer this yourself.

Comment: There is no "for function". It's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  `map` and list comprehensions will have similar performance. Anyway, file I/O will probably be the bottleneck.

Comment: I suggest you read [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: using 'for' and the lists aren't  long,10-15 integers only.

Comment: map returns a generator object(does not evaluate all at once). In you case, if your lists are small, just use comprenhension list.

Comment: How are you creating each list of strings?

Comment: The best way to find out what is faster is to measure. I mean it. Theory can go wrong in special cases. The speed could be different for your data. If someone here says A is faster and you measure that B is faster, the measurement wins every time. In the end, there is really no point in asking this kind of question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[int(x, 10) for x in lst]` is at least significantly faster than your two ways:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> setup = "lst = ['10','12','31','41','15']"

>>> timeit('map(int, lst)', setup)
4.454881024529442

>>> timeit('[int(x) for x in lst]', setup)
4.7153410495946275

>>> timeit('[int(x, 10) for x in lst]', setup)
1.6508196962672343
```

Tested with Python 2.7.11 (I'm assuming you use Python 2 because otherwise your `lst1=map(...)` would be misleading).

Comment: Thank you.I really appreciate that.

Comment: On Python 3, I'm seeing negligible performance differences.  Indeed I am getting the original comprehension as slightly faster and actually `list(map(int, lst))`  as the fastest approach, again, only slightly. Was this an issue in Python 2 `int` that was fixed in Python 3?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, in Python 3 I also get just tiny differences, all get around 1.25 seconds. Don't know why it differs so much between Python 2 and 3. I just know the explicit-base-10 "trick" from some "why is float faster than int" thread, maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2grsb5/why_is_int_slower_than_float_when_converting_a/) and maybe you can find some more explanation there.